# How to catch FlinkRuntimeException in Flink producer and skip failed messages

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-flink

Is there any way to catch FlinkRuntimeException and handle it properly preventing Flink job restating?

**Code sample which throws the FlinkRuntimeException:**

```
    int numberOfRows = 1;
    int rowsPerSecond = 1;

    DataStream<String> stream = environment.addSource(
                    new DataGeneratorSource<>(
                            RandomGenerator.stringGenerator(1050000), // max.message.bytes=1048588
                            rowsPerSecond,
                            (long) numberOfRows),
                    TypeInformation.of(String.class))
            .setParallelism(1)
            .name("string-generator");


    KafkaSinkBuilder<String> builder = KafkaSink.<String>builder()
            .setBootstrapServers("localhost:9092")
            .setDeliverGuarantee(DeliveryGuarantee.AT_LEAST_ONCE)
            .setRecordSerializer(
                    KafkaRecordSerializationSchema.builder().setTopic("test.output")
                            .setValueSerializationSchema(new SimpleStringSchema())
                            .build());


    KafkaSink<String> sink = builder.build();

    stream.sinkTo(sink).setParallelism(1).name("output-producer");
```

**Exception Stack Trace:**

> 2022-06-02/14:01:45.066/PDT [flink-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] INFO  output-producer: Writer -> output-producer: Committer (1/1) (a66beca5a05c1c27691f7b94ca6ac025)
> switched from RUNNING to FAILED on 271b1b90-7d6b-4a34-8116-3de6faa8a9bf @ 127.0.0.1 (dataPort=-1).
> org.apache.flink.util.FlinkRuntimeException: Failed to send data to Kafka null with FlinkKafkaInternalProducer{transactionalId='null', inTransaction=false, closed=false}
> at org.apache.flink.connector.kafka.sink.KafkaWriter$WriterCallback.throwException(KafkaWriter.java:440) ~[flink-connector-kafka-1.15.0.jar:1.15.0]
> at org.apache.flink.connector.kafka.sink.KafkaWriter$WriterCallback.lambda$onCompletion$0(KafkaWriter.java:421) ~[flink-connector-kafka-1.15.0.jar:1.15.0]
> at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTaskActionExecutor$1.runThrowing(StreamTaskActionExecutor.java:50) ~[flink-streaming-java-1.15.0.jar:1.15.0]
> at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.mailbox.Mail.run(Mail.java:90) ~[flink-streaming-java-1.15.0.jar:1.15.0]
> at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.mailbox.MailboxProcessor.processMailsNonBlocking(MailboxProcessor.java:353) ~[flink-streaming-java-1.15.0.jar:1.15.0]
> at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.mailbox.MailboxProcessor.processMail(MailboxProcessor.java:317) ~[flink-streaming-java-1.15.0.jar:1.15.0]
> at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.mailbox.MailboxProcessor.runMailboxLoop(MailboxProcessor.java:201) ~[flink-streaming-java-1.15.0.jar:1.15.0]
> at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.runMailboxLoop(StreamTask.java:804) ~[flink-streaming-java-1.15.0.jar:1.15.0]
> at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.invoke(StreamTask.java:753) ~[flink-streaming-java-1.15.0.jar:1.15.0]
> at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.runWithSystemExitMonitoring(Task.java:948) ~[flink-runtime-1.15.0.jar:1.15.0]
> at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.restoreAndInvoke(Task.java:927) ~[flink-runtime-1.15.0.jar:1.15.0]
> at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.doRun(Task.java:741) ~[flink-runtime-1.15.0.jar:1.15.0]
> at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:563) ~[flink-runtime-1.15.0.jar:1.15.0]
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[?:1.8.0_292]
> Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.RecordTooLargeException: The message is 1050088 bytes when serialized which is larger than 1048576, which is the value of the max.request.size configuration.

Comment: Hi, did you figure the solution to this problem?

Comment: @guru yes, I created my own delivery callback  in [KafkaWriter](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/master/flink-connectors/flink-connector-kafka/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/connector/kafka/sink/KafkaWriter.java#L144). For this purpose I copied all KafkaWriter dependencies  (17 classes)  from "org/apache/flink/connector/kafka/sink" package to my project because all of them have "package access" only.
`this.deliveryCallback = new MyOwnCallback ...`